Recessed iPad in wall with PoE (Power/Data) and audio out
I built my shower with speakers embedded in the walls. I now want to add a recessed iPad which will connect to the speakers via audio output and I want to provide data/power to the iPad via PoE. According to Apple, the iPad only has a single USB-C output: https://www.apple.com/ipad-10.9/specs/.
I'm not sure what equipment I will need so that my iPad can receive data/power via PoE and also be able to audio out into my speaker system. I've included an overview of my bathroom layout and some photos for clarity. I realize I could just throw the iPad in the utility space, but the point of it being recessed is so that I can access the device while in the shower to select the music/video/whatever. I found a solution from a manufacturer that makes the mount that protects the iPad from water/moisture and allows for touch screen, but they don't provide the devices for ethernet/power/audio. For that I have my Ubiquiti switches for PoE, PoE+, and PoE++ ports (whichever is necessary to power this device), but I don't know what other equipment I need to power/data/audio my iPad.
For clarity, this is the PoE device I came across (power/data) but no audio: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09M2N3NHX/ref=cm_sw_r_apa_i_89WSYB3843GQ3F6PHN6R_1?_encoding=UTF8&th=1.
Thanks!









AFAIK iPads have a combo charger/data port.  What are your speaker inputs—do they connect via Bluetooth, or are you planning on using the iPad's data/charging port to communicate with the speakers/amp?  How are you powering your speakers?  Gotta link to the speaker setup?

The speakers have an audio input jack. So I need to have an audio output from the iPad and an audio input to the speaker system box where all the speakers are connected (second last photo above).

Does each speaker have its own audio jack?  What's your plan for connecting the iPad to all 4 speakers?

The speakers connect to the box in the utility space, I don't know what the box is called, but the second last photo shows all the speakers plugged into this box and that box has an audio input port. I tested this out with my computer and the speakers work.

So your problrm is not getting signal from iPad to speakers.  It's getting signal from iPad to amp/control box.  Why can't you simply run a long 3.5mm stereo cable from iPad to box?

Unless you are really tied to the Apple ecosystem, you may want to consider Android instead. A lot less expensive (once you get away from the very top brands/models) so if the humidity gets to be too much, despite the protective enclosure, replacement won't be as bad.
Android tablets typically include an audio jack, solving the "connect to speakers" problem.
But I would extremely wary of having an internet-connected device with a camera in my shower.
Unfortunately, the go-to for "embed a small nice color touch-screen in a product" has now become "Android tablet". (Apple is no better in this respect, but manufacturers of other products use Android for the same reason I recommend it here - a lot less expensive than an iPad.) In a perfect world, we'd have a "no camera, no microphone, perhaps somewhat limited in other ways" device with a color touch-screen and a decent CPU for creating specialized devices. That is still true for mass-market devices (e.g., printers) where designing and building a device-specific system is cost-effective. But for many other things a consumer-grade tablet - with all its advantages (primarily cost) and disadvantages (complex operating system beyond your easy control; vulnerability to outside systems; camera even if you don't need it; etc.) has become the default. </rant>

The enclosure spec ends up covering up the front-facing camera, so no privacy issue there.

Also, I thought about Android, but I already have so many devices in the apple ecosystem.
